# Why the logoff only works locally but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logoff

Im using this code to do the logoff

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
    {

         FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        // Drop all the information held in the session
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();

        // clear authentication cookie
        HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

        // clear session cookie
        HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
        cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);
        foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
        {
            Request.Cookies.Remove(cookie);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    }
```

and its work fine local, but when I publish my app in the server, even if user already logoff, the page still displays if user clicks browser's `Back` button.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: `Request.Cookies.Remove()` is useless.

Comment: `Request.Cookies.Remove` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: The phrase "doesn't work" is useless in terms of diagnostic information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything in this function beyond FormsAuthentication.SignOut() and Session.Abandon() is completely redundant in terms of ending session.

Comment: Your above code is fine!! One thing to note is that on Server if Domain property is set on FormsAuthentication cookie when logging in, you must set when expirying the cookie on when you log out..

Comment: Ok, its work fine local because I cant go back with the button back in the browser but in the server I can go back in my app and stay logged

Comment: Is it really logged in after clicking the back button, or just showing you the last page.  You can force the browser to not cache that page thereby stopping folks from "going back".

Comment: How can I do that? I think the user stay active in the cookie and allows me to going back in the application

Comment: When you press the Back button of your browser, the server is not requested. The last rendered page is shown from the cache. The user is not authenticated. If he attempts to do some action he will be redirected to the logon page.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you are simply seeing the cached version of the page.

If you hit CTRL+F5 does it ask you to log in again?

If you REALLY want to disabled this see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10909477/148998) given by MiBu to prevent caching of a secure page.